Find APK Library Dependencies in Flutter
On compiling a Flutter App to APK and looking in the APK analyser I find that 68% of the size of my app is accounted for by one library libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so
Trying to find out now where this dependency comes from, if is it necessary and can I exclude it.
My pubspec.yaml delcares the following depencies
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

I have tried calling 'flutter pub deps' as per this stackoverflow but it doesn't show up there. I have also looked at the dependencies tab under the Android Studio Project Structure and I can't find it there either.
Any additional suggestions as to either where to look or why it may be included would be gratefully received.

Having now built and released the App the APK size has dropped considerably - so it seems that these additional dependencies are either a) stripped out or b) needed for debug runs only

The library in question is part of the Vulkan validation layers, which are used for debugging Vulkan API calls. Here is documentation. Vulkan is the graphic api which is used by Flutter's new Impeller engine on Android.
It appears in your app, because flutter build system includes it in debug builds of your app. It was made intentionally, but this library does not affect your production.
Here is GitHub issue where flutter team discuss this topic and pull request where it was added.
If you do not want this lib to be added to your builds, you can modify your android/app/build.gradle(.kts) like this:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            excludes.add("**/libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so")
        }
    }
}

This configuration snippet will prevent the Vulkan validation library from being packaged into your APK

Thanks for this clarification - really useful to know!
